# How to populate a list with text from website

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using this to populate a list(wordlist) from Amazon website product page hoping to get this text "Haz clic para obtener una vista ampliada" :

```
wordlist.append(WebDriverWait(robotel, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span#canvasCaption"))).text)
```

Problem is that when I do it in a loop, for multiple product pages sometimes for some products wordlist is empty, but then if I test again for the same product page wordlist gets populated.

I can't fiind the reason for this, so please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your line of code seems just perfect.

However, to avoid the empty wordlist you can additionally implement either/all of the following approaches:

- As you are iterating through a loop some product pages and some products may take longer time to render, so you may need to increase the [waiting time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for ***30*** secs to ***45*** secs,
- Beside considering the *`id`* attribute you can append some other attributes as well, e.g. *`class`*, *`aria-label`*, *`href`*, *`data-a-hires`*, *`alt`*, etc

Comment: I can't fiind any other diffrence between 2 product pages : one which has zoom function (you can move the mouse over picture to see it zoomed in) and one which has no zoom function.  I will give it a try with longer waiting time, thank you !